# Install macOS Catalina.app does not appear to be a valid OS installer application

Tags: macos, catalina

I've seen this error a lot googling around and a lot of possible solutions but non of them worked for me.

I have a Mac on High Sierra and I need to create a bootable media for Catalina but when I download it from the store it downloads a 13mb file (not the full installer). I got to run the installer until it asks for a restart so I have all the install files on `/macOS Install Data/` but I can't find a way to copy them to my pendrive.

I've tried this:

```
sudo mkdir /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport

sudo cp -R /macOS\ Install\ Data/ Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport/
```

However, even though it seems that it is creating the new dir, when I copy it says "No such file or directory"

Any help with this would be really appreciated since I've literally lost two days on my job with is and I am getting no response from Apple.. Can't believe that something so simple as creating a bootable media turns out to be so frustrating with Apple

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. Sounds like you received a download for upgrading your Mac rather than for creating bootable medium. What happens if you remove the tiny installer you have and use this link to download Catalina again, do you get another tiny installer or the full macOS? https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. That's problem but I've tried removing it and downloading it again but I always get the same small file. I've tried both the link and through the store but no luck. I also found some unofficial sites where there seems to be the full installer but I don't want to risk to end up installing a beta version or something that might cause issues in the future

Comment: Have you tried using the command `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.15.7`?

Comment: @Allan, Just an FYI, `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.15.7` only works from **macOS Catalina** and the OP is running **macOS High Sierra**, so this will not work for him.

Comment: If OP can install Catalina parallel with High Sierra by partitioning the disk(I assume he just don't want to upgrade) then he could use @Allans suggestion.

Comment: All I needed was the full installer to create the bootable media. I have other macs with Catalina installed on them so I ran the update fetch but I was getting this error at first: Downloading and installing 10.15.7 installer
SUPreferenceManager: Failed to set object of class: __NSCFConstantString for key: LastRecommendedMajorOSBundleIdentifier with error: Error Domain=SUPreferenceManagerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
I tried a few hours later and I have absolutely no idea why, but it suddenly worked and it actually fetched the 8gb installer so I was able to create the boot media. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

I have given up trying to use Apple’s official methods for these things, as they seem determined to make it difficult.

Instead I have turned to the scripts used by Mac network admins, who largely don’t have the time to deal with Apple’s shenanigans because they need to get their work done.

Toward that end there are two scripts that you can use. Both are called `installinstallmacos.py` and they are designed to download (direct from Apple’s servers) the full and official installers.

The first of these is:

- [munki/macadmin-scripts/installinstallmacos.py](https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/main/installinstallmacos.py)

However, there is also a well-maintained fork which has some nice extra features which you can find at

- [grahampugh/macadmin-scripts/installinstallmacos.py](https://github.com/grahampugh/macadmin-scripts/blob/master/installinstallmacos.py)

Download one (or both) and run them via `sudo installinstallmacos.py` and follow the on-screen instructions.

Only one additional note/tip: the file will be downloaded to the current directory/folder that you are in when you run the command, so I recommend something like this:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo installinstallmacos.py
```

to make sure that you know where the files end up. (They will also be owned by root so you’ll need to take that into account when you delete them once you are done.)